# How to solve string splitting issue having pharentesis on the output when working with str-split and Sass

Tags: sass

I have been messing around with `sass` trying to understand how `directives` and `at-rules` work in this environment.

Very simple question:

I am trying to transform a string into a list of strings.

e.g: `a, b, c` into `"a", "b", "c"`.

While trying to write this simple `@function` I have been seeing this odd behavior:

```
@function split($string, $search) {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);
  @while $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1), split(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search);
  }
  @return $string;
}

@debug split("b c b", " ") //test.scss:130 DEBUG: "b", ("c", "b")
```

I would like to see the desired output without the parenthesis: `"b", "c", "b"`.

How can I achieve this and where do these parenthesis come from after all?

Comment: I don't see any parenthesis if I use your `@function` in a selector instead of the `@debug` tag.

Comment: This is very odd... I am using ```dart-sass``` with ```reactjs``` in ```vscode```. I am watching the ```logs``` on the terminal using the command ```sass --watch test.scss:Child.css ```. Even when I check the ```length``` using ```@debug length(split("b c b", " "));``` I get a output of 2, instead of 3.

Comment: @Arkellys I have created a really dummy ```mixin``` to test this issue: ```@mixin dummy() {
  padding: #{length(split("b c b", " "))}rem;
}``` and assign it to a generic selector ```h2 {
  @include dummy;
}``` and get the following output: ```h2 {
  padding: 2rem; }```. The desired value would be ```3rem``` if there was not a parenthesis splitting the result of my ```function```. Don't you see this same output on your console?

Comment: As what I can see, the output is a nested list. Its a list, which it second instance is another list. output: ```index 1: b``` ```index 2: (c , b)```

Comment: I tested the code on SassMeister which might not use dart-sass. Can you edit your question to add the `@mixin` example?

Comment: the ```@mixin``` I mentioned on my comment? I did a hacky thing to get my desired output. ```$li: split("b c b", " ");
@debug join(nth($li, 1), nth($li, 2));``` to test if I could flatten this, considering it a nested list and it proved to be a nested list as it came with the following result: ```test.scss:134 DEBUG: "b", "c", "b"```. No I am wondering how to fix this at the original function. I am now thinking a bit of how to flatten this so called nested list in a ```function```

Comment: I am from the javascript world so I can only imagine myself using a ```flat()``` on this and getting this out of my way =D

Comment: Just did ```@return join(str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1), split(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search));``` on the @return statement of the ```split``` function and it worked =D

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [append](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/list#append) function too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly I ended up understanding that somehow I am getting nested lists as a output with this `function` so I have added the function `join()` at the `return` statement and now the result is a flattened list of `strings`.

```
@function split($string, $search) {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);
  @while $index {
    @return join(str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1), split(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search));
  }
 @return $string
}

@debug split("a b c b", " "); //test.scss:130 DEBUG: "a" "b" "c" "b"
```

The question I leave here is: why I am getting a nested list as an output on my question?

Please note that I am on the following environment: `vscode` using `dart-sass` in `reactjs`.